# Divisibility by 11

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm trying to prove that a number $a_n=a_0+a_1 \cdot 10^1+...+c_n\cdot 10^n$ is divisible by 11 iff $a_0-a_1+a_2-...+(a_n)\cdot(-1)^{n+1}$ is divisible by 11.

I began my proof and I found out that I first need to prove that $10^k+(-1)^{k+1}$ is divisible by 11 for all $k\in \mathbb{N} $.

I tried to prove this with induction:

for $k=1$ we get $t_1=10^1+(-1)^{1+1}=11$

now I assume $t_k=10^k+(-1)^{k+1}$ is divisible by 11.

need to prove that: $\\$ $t_{k+1}=10^{k+1}+(-1)^{k+2}=10^{k+1}+(-1)^{k}$
is divisible by 11.

I looked at:

$t_{k+1}-t_{k}=10^{k+1}+(-1)^{k}-10^k-(-1)^{k+1}=9\cdot 10^k +2\cdot (-1)^k$

and now I'm stuck :(

if you have any idea how can I complete my proof I will be very grateful!

Thank You All!

Comment: $10 = (11-1)$ so $10^k = (11-1)^k$.  Applying binomial theorem finishes the problem.

Comment: Consider instead $t_{k+1}-10t_k$ (which is to say, keep subtracting $t_k$ from that you have until interesting things happen). Much easier.

Comment: Are you familiar with congruences or modular arithmetic, such as. $\,10\equiv -1\pmod{11}\,$?

Comment: $\!\bmod 11\!:\ 10\equiv -1\Rightarrow 10^k\equiv (-1)^k\,$ by the Congruence Power Rule in the linked dupe (which is an *inductive* extension of the Product Rule).

Comment: More generally **casting out elevens** is a special case of the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), an inductive extension of both the Sum & Product Rules, see the 2nd linked dupe.

Comment: In the 3rd linked dupe I explain how the inductive step (below) in a proof using divisibility language is just a special case of the Congruence Product Rule. $$\large \rm  11\mid \underbrace{10^n\!-(-1)^n}_{\Large a_n}\Rightarrow 11\mid 11(10^n)-(10^n\!-(-1)^n)\ [= \underbrace{10^{n+1}\!-(-1)^{n+1}}_{\Large a_{n+1}}]\qquad $$

Comment: $10^k + (-1)^{k+1}= 11M$. so $10(10^k + (-1)^{k+1} = 10^{k+1} +(-1)^{k+1}10=110M$  So $10^{k+1} + (-1)^{k+1}10 - (-1)^{k+1}\cdot 11= 110M +  - (-1)^{k+1}\cdot 11$.  And so $10^{k+1} -(-1)^{k+1} = 10^{k+1} + (-1)^{k+2} = 11(10M - (-1)^{k+1})$.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that $$y^k-x^k = (y-x)\sum_{m=0}^{k} y^m x^{k-m}$$
(you can prove this for yourself as the right hand side is a telescoping sum). Then $$10^k + (-1)^{k+1} = 11 \sum_{m=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-m} 10^m$$
which is divisible by 11.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$
10^{k+1}+(-1)^{k+2}=10^{k+1}+(-1)^{k+1}\cdot 10-(-1)^{k+1}\cdot 11=10 \cdot \left(10^{k}+(-1)^{k+1}\right)-(-1)^{k+1}\cdot 11
$$

**Alternate alternate solution** When $k=2l$ is even then
$$
10^{2l}-1=100^l-1=(100-1)( \mbox{ junk }) 
$$

When $k=2l+1$ is odd then
$$
10^{2l+1}+1=10^{2l+1}-10+11=10 (100^l-1) +11=10 (100-1)( \mbox{ junk })  +11
$$

Answer (score 0):

This follows right away from the fact that $10\equiv-1\pmod{11}$.  For then $10^n\equiv (-1)^n\pmod{11}$.  So the alternating sum of the digits is congruent to the number modulo  $11$.